# How to consider Daylight Saving Time in Linux Ubantu using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, timezone, date-conversion

I've a `C#` Program what needs to convert from EST to UTC. Following function works perfectly in `Linux` except the fact that it's adding an hour extra means rather than adding 4 hours, it's adding 5 hours. This is because of DayLightSaving.

I've tried to use

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime()
```

but it's returning wrong value in `Linux` Ubuntu -- It should be true but returning as false.

How can I solve this issue in `Linux`?

```
private DateTime ConvertToUTCHHmm(DateTime dateValue)
        {
            // default to date for debuging, should be overwritten
            DateTime dateTimeUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-120);

            try
            {
                // Convert EST to UTC - Old Method of conversion.
                TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
                
                dateTimeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateValue, est);
                // Check Daylight Saving Time..
                DateTime thisTime = DateTime.Now;
                bool isDaylight = TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(thisTime);
                _logger.LogDebug(String.Format(" IsDaylightSavingTime : {0}", isDaylight));
                if (isDaylight) // returns as false. It supposed to be true
                    dateTimeUtc = dateTimeUtc.AddHours(-1);
                _logger.LogDebug(String.Format("TimeZoneInfo Old Process : {0} Converted Time : {1}", est, dateTimeUtc));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("TimeZoneInfo Old Process Error - " + ex.Message);
            }

            return dateTimeUtc;
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally we fixed the issue. Issue was with this line -

```
bool isDaylight = TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(thisTime);
```

We can't get the New York timezone with Local as Server is running in UTC. So we had to change the code to get New York TimeZone and everything worked perfectly.

```
TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
```

Here is the full method.

```
private DateTime ConvertToUTCHHmm(DateTime dateValue)
        {
            // default to date for debuging, should be overwritten
            DateTime dateTimeUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-120);

            try
            {
                // Convert EST to UTC - Old Method of conversion.
                TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
                dateTimeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateValue, est);
                // Check Daylight Saving Time..
                DateTime thisTime = DateTime.Now;
                TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
                bool isDaylight = tst.IsDaylightSavingTime(thisTime);
                _logger.LogDebug(String.Format(" IsDaylightSavingTime : {0}", isDaylight));
                if (isDaylight)
                    dateTimeUtc = dateTimeUtc.AddHours(-1);
                _logger.LogDebug(String.Format("TimeZoneInfo Old Process : {0} Converted Time : {1}", est, dateTimeUtc));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("TimeZoneInfo Old Process Error - " + ex.Message);
            }

            return dateTimeUtc;
        }
```

Comment: No, this is still broken. Whether or not DST is *currently* in effect doesn't change whether it *was* in effect at the time of `dateValue`. You shouldn't need to do anything other than call `ConvertTimeToUtc` - that should take daylight saving time into account automatically.